# Wordpress post not showing up title when redirected from permalink

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created my own theme. On my front page (`index.php`), I am showing a snippet of posts, with 'Read More' link in the end. So when I click read more, I get redirected to that post's page (`localhost/wordpress/2014/post-title/`), but there, I can't see the title of the post, but all the content.

**Code for snippet in index.php**

```
<div id="blog" class="container">

        <?php query_posts('showposts=3'); ?>
        <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="post col-md-4">
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

            <div class="entry">  
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

                <?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?>
                <p class="postmetadata">
                <?php _e('Filed under&#58;'); ?> <?php the_category(', ') ?> <?php _e('by'); ?> <?php  the_author(); ?><br />
                <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?> <?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' &#124; ', ''); ?>

                </p>

            </div>
        </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>

        <div class="navigation">
        <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>


    </div>
```

So how do I get the post title there?

Comment: Do you have single.php in your theme ? If you do, please post its code as well.

Comment: Oh! I don't have that file included.

Answer (score 0):

I think people can't help you to solve this with this code. If that post's page doesn't show the post title, then you need to check on `single.php`

Probably, you may have forgot to add the `<?php the_title(); ?>` part in that `single.php` file.

Comment: I am not having single.php file in my theme folder. Is it necessary to add?

Comment: Yes, Single.php is important for any theme unless you're using a Child Theme.